# No TabController for ${widget.runtimeType} in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, tabbar

I have defined the TabController but it says no controller define for **Widget.type**
I have also try without controller but same error occur.
The  error is:

```
 **'No TabController for ${widget.runtimeType}.\n'
          'When creating a ${widget.runtimeType}, you must either provide an explicit '
          'TabController using the "controller" property, or you must ensure that there 
             'is a DefaultTabController above the ${widget.runtimeType}.\n'
              'In this case, there was neither an explicit controller nor a default controller.',**
```

Code

```dart
class _homePageState extends State<homePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _controller;
  static const List<Widget> _tabs = [
    Tab(
      icon: Icon(Icons.home),
    ),
    Tab(
      icon: Icon(Icons.tv),
    ),
    Tab(
      icon: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle),
    )
  ];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
    _controller.animateTo(2);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("title"),
          actions: [
            InkWell(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Icon(Icons.search),
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Icon(Icons.messenger),
            ),
          ],
          bottom: TabBar(controller: _controller, tabs: _tabs),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [Text("data"), Text("list"), Text("list")],
        ));
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Include `TabBarView(controller: _controller`

```dart
 body: TabBarView(
      controller: _controller  
     children: [
       Text("data"),
       Text("list"),
       Text("list")
```

Full widget

```dart
class homePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const homePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<homePage> createState() => _homePageState();
}

class _homePageState extends State<homePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _controller;
  static const List<Widget> _tabs = [
    Tab(
      icon: Icon(Icons.home),
    ),
    Tab(
      icon: Icon(Icons.tv),
    ),
    Tab(
      icon: Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle),
    )
  ];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
    _controller.animateTo(2);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("title"),
          actions: [
            InkWell(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Icon(Icons.search),
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Icon(Icons.messenger),
            ),
          ],
          bottom: TabBar(controller: _controller, tabs: _tabs),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _controller,
          children: [Text("data"), Text("list"), Text("list")],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: again same error.

Comment: try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: same error.....

Comment: remove your `homePage` widget and place my snippet, now save the file, do `flutter clean` and rebuild the app, if fails restart the IDE.